# How prove this $\{a\}\cdot\{b\}\cdot\{c\}=0$ if $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Interesting problem**

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers such that
>   $$\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor$$
>   for all postive integers $n$.
>   Show that:
>   $$\{a\}\cdot\{b\}\cdot\{c\}=0$$
>   where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

My partial work: since for any postive intger $n$,have
$$\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor$$
then we have
$$a+b=c$$
because consider
$$\Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor}{\lfloor nc\rfloor}=1$$
since
$x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor \le x$,so we have
$$na+nb-2<\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor\le na+nb$$
so
$$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor}{\lfloor nc\rfloor}=\dfrac{a+b}{c}$$
I guess we can use by contradiction prove this. Assume that
$\{a\}\cdot\{b\}\cdot\{c\}\neq0$, then $a,b,c$ all not integer.

Comment: It's a nice problem.Can you please tell us where you got it from?

Comment: If $a+b=c$ then it also follows that $\{na\} + \{nb\} = \{nc\}$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Winther, no. Take $a = \frac16, b = \frac16, c = \frac13, n = 3, 4, 5$.

Comment: @Jihad If $\lfloor na \rfloor + \lfloor nb \rfloor = \lfloor nc \rfloor$ then using the definition of the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{x\}$ the claim follows. Your example is not a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Winther, oh, you meant in the context of this problem.

Comment: Hello,This problem is from china old  Mathematical Olympiad book，see http://book.kongfz.com/5097/225644243/

Comment: One possible line of attack: Assume that $a$ and $b$ are not integers. Then try to find $n$ s.t. $\{na\} + \{nb\} \geq 1$ contradicting that $\{na\} + \{nb\} = \{nc\} < 1$. For example if we had $a = 0.35$ and $b=0.55$ then with $n=5$ we get $\{na\} + \{nb\} = 1.25$. I think this should always be possible (seems like pigeonhole arguments could work), but have not managed to work out the details yet.

Comment: \begin{align}
   \lfloor 3(1.3)\rfloor + \lfloor 3(2.2)\rfloor &=\lfloor 3(3.3)\rfloor \\
   \{1.3\} \cdot \{2.2\} \cdot \{3.3\} &= 0.018
\end{align}

So, I'm assuming you mean for all $n$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $n=1$ one gets $\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor=\lfloor c\rfloor$. Subtracting $n$ times that equation from the given one gives
$$
  \lfloor n\{a\}\rfloor+\lfloor n\{b\}\rfloor=\lfloor n\{c\}\rfloor \quad\text{for all $n\in\Bbb N$,}
$$
and together with $\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor=\lfloor c\rfloor$ these equations also imply the original ones. But now one only has the fractional parts $a'=\{a\}$, $b'=\{b\}$ and $c'=\{c\}$ in the formulation of the problem.
This means it suffices to show the stated result in the special case $a,b,c\in[0,1)$. I will henceforth assume that.

First I show the conditions imply $a+b=c$. Suppose this equation fails, then choose $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a+b-c|\geq\frac2n$. From $|na+nb-nc|\geq2$ it follows that $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor\neq\lfloor nc\rfloor$, a contradiction.

It remains to prove that for $a,b\in(0,1)$ there always exists some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\{na\}+\{nb\}\geq1$, since that means $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=nc-(\{na\}+\{nb\})=\lfloor nc\rfloor-1$ contradicting the hypothesis; assuming that, the cases of the reduced problem that satisfy the hypothesis must have $a=0\lor b=0$, which means that one has $\{a\}\cdot\{b\}=0$ in the original problem, stronger than what was needed.

Proving the existence of such an $n$ is a bit technical. If $a+b\geq1$ one can take $n=1$, so assume that $a+b<1$. Choosing $N>0$ with $\frac2N<\min(a,b,1-a-b)$, I claim there exists some $m$ such that $ma$ and $mb$ are both no further than $\frac1N$ from the nearest integer (call the actual differences $\epsilon_a,\epsilon_b$). Then one can take $n=m-1$ because $na\equiv -a+\epsilon_a\pmod1$ implies (due to the smallness of $\epsilon_a$) that $\{na\}=1-a+\epsilon_a$ and similarly $\{nb\}=1-b+\epsilon_b$; combining the two equations gives that $\{na\}+\{nb\}=2-a-b+\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b\geq1+(1-a-b-\frac2N)>1$.

The claim can be proved using the pigeonhole principle: the pairs of remainders modulo$~N$ of $\lfloor mNa\rfloor$ and of $\lfloor mNb\rfloor$ can take only finitely many (namely $N^2$) different values as $m$ varies, so there exist $m_1<m_2$ for which the same pair is obtained; then taking $m=m_2-m_1$, one has that the numbers $ma$ and $mb$ are both at distance less than $\frac1N$ from an integer.

Answer (score 3):

I will show a partial result. If $a,b,c$ are rational numbers then $a$ and $b$ cannot both be non-integers, i.e. we have $\{a\}\cdot \{b\}\cdot \{c\} = 0$.

We can wlog assume that $0 \leq a,b,c < 1$ since any integer-part can be subtracted away. We will also use OPs results that $a+b=c$. This results also implies

$$\{na\} + \{nb\} = \{nc\}$$

for all $n>0$. In the following we will assume that both $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers in $(0,1)$. Then there exist integers $k,N,p,M$ s.t.

$$a = \frac{k}{N}~~~~\text{and}~~~~b = \frac{p}{M}$$

with $k<N$, $p<M$, $(k,N)=1$ and $(p,M)=1$. First we note that $$\{c\} = \{a\} + \{b\} = \frac{k}{n} + \frac{p}{m}$$

By taking $n = NM-1$ and using the first equality above we get

$$\{na\} + \{nb\} = \{Mk-\frac{k}{N}\} + \{Np-\frac{p}{M}\} = 1 - \frac{k}{N} + 1- \frac{p}{M} = 2 - \{c\}$$

since $Mk,Np$ are integers and $0 < \frac{k}{N},\frac{p}{M} < 1$. It now follows that

$$\{nc\} + \{c\} = 2$$

which is impossible since $\{c\},\{nc\} < 1$. There is one last case that is not covered by the argument above and that is if $a+b = 1$. This case is however ruled out by $\{a\} + \{b\} = 1 \not= \{c\} = 0$.

Comment: Probably I finished your result.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Winther](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147873/winther) result I can finish the proof for other cases. In order to do this we have to deduce this problem to rationals.

According to little bit stricter version of [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem#Simultaneous_Version) we can find infinitely many pairs of fraction $\left(\frac{p_1}q, \frac{p_2}q\right)$ with the following property:

$$\max\left(\left|a - \frac{p_1}q\right|, \left|b - \frac{p_2}q\right|\right) < q^{-\frac32}.$$

Infinitely many means that we can make $q$ as large as we want, we will choose it later. Finally, let's take $n = q-1$:

$$
\{n\frac{p_1}{q}\} + \{n\frac{p_2}{q}\} = \{1-\frac{p_1}{q}\} + \{1-\frac{p_2}{q}\} = 2 - \frac{p_1}{q}-\frac{p_2}{q} =\\
= 2 - \{c\} + \left(a - \frac{p_1}{q}\right) + \left(b - \frac{p_2}{q}\right) = 2 - \{c\}+\frac{\alpha}{q}, \alpha \in [-2, 2]
$$

Also from Dirichlet's theorem we know that $n\left(a - \frac{p_1}{q}\right) < q^{-\frac12}$ and the same thing with $b$. Finally we can get:

$$
2 - \alpha q^{-\frac12} = \{nc\}+\{c\} \leq 1 + \{c\}, \alpha \in [-4, 4]
$$

Now we can take very large $q$ and get contradiction.

**Edit**. In fact I omitted one little issue, namely, why the following implication is true?

$$
(na - n\frac{p_1}q) < q^{-\frac12} \Rightarrow (\{na\} - \{n\frac{p_1}q\}) < q^{-\frac12}
$$

Unfortunately, it is not true in every single case, but in our situation we can handle it. Remember that $n = q-1$. The problem can occur if there is an $A \in \mathbb{Z}$ (in fact $A = p_1$) such that

$$
n\frac{p_1}q=(q-1)\frac{p_1}q = p_1 - \frac{p_1}q < A < (q-1)a = na
$$

And also we know that distance between $n\frac{p_1}q$ and $na$ less than $q^{-\frac12}$. Last thing that we should mention is that $\frac{p_1}q > \frac{a}2 > 0$ since $\frac{p_1}q$ is close to $a \neq 0$.