# proof involving floor functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am looking at a problem that roughly says

> If $a,b \in [0,1)$, and $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor n(a+b)\rfloor$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a=0$ or $b=0$.

The proof that was supplied was the following:

> Assume $ab\neq 0$ and write $a=2^{-a_1}+2^{-a_2}+\ldots+2^{-a_s}$, and $b=2^{-b_1}+2^{-b_2}+\ldots+2^{-b_t}$, and wlog let $b_t\geq a_s$. Then taking $n=2^{b_t}-1$ gives
> $$\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\Big\lfloor \sum_i 2^{b_t-a_i}-a\Big\rfloor+\Big\lfloor \sum_i 2^{b_t-b_i}-b\Big\rfloor=\sum_i 2^{b_t-a_i}-1+\sum_i 2^{b_t-b_i}-1,$$
> whereas the RHS becomes
> $$\lfloor n(a+b)\rfloor=\Big\lfloor\sum_i 2^{b_t-a_i}+\sum_i 2^{b_t-b_i}-a-b\Big\rfloor=\sum_i 2^{b_t-a_i}+\sum_i 2^{b_t-b_i}-1,$$
> a contradiction.

However as far as I can see this only applies if $a,b$ have finite decimal representations in base 2. Once one generalises to arbitrary $a,b\in[0,1)$ I think this proof becomes insufficient.

So I was wondering if there is a proof that can show this result for all such $a,b$, or if this result actually fails without the assumption that $a,b$ have finite base 2 decimal representations.

Comment: FYI, I believe the very similar question of [How prove this $\{a\}\cdot\{b\}\cdot\{c\}=0$ if $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089274/602049) would be of interest, & likely also of some use, to you.

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, there’s a problem with the argument even for $a$ and $b$ with finite binary decimal expansions: if $a+b>1$, $$\left\lfloor\sum_i2^{b_t-a_i}+\sum_i2^{b_t-b_i}-a-b\right\rfloor=\sum_i2^{b_t-a_i}+\sum_i2^{b_t-b_i}-2\;,$$ and in that case there’s no contradiction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I noticed the same issue, wrote & posted a comment, but then deleted it. This is because I realized that since $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor n(a+b)\rfloor$ is true for every natural $n$, it must be true for $n = 1$. This gives $\lfloor a\rfloor + \lfloor b\rfloor = \lfloor a + b\rfloor$. The LHS is $0 + 0 = 0$, so the RHS must be $0$ also, i.e., $a + b \lt 1$. I believe this should have been stated explicitly in the proof to help avoid confusion & misunderstanding.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Ah, good point; thanks. (And yes, I think that it really does need to be stated.)

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for the link, the answer there addresses my question.