# How can I prove $\{a+b\}\{a-c\}\{a-d\}=0$ if the folowing relation holds for all positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that if are $a, b, c, d$ real numbers for which holds $\lfloor na \rfloor+\lfloor nb \rfloor=\lfloor nc \rfloor+\lfloor nd \rfloor$ for all positive integers $n$ then $\{a+b\}\{a-c\}\{a-d\}=0$.

I was able to prove $a+b=c+d$ using the fact that $\frac{\lfloor an \rfloor+\lfloor bn \rfloor}{\lfloor cn \rfloor+\lfloor dn \rfloor}$ converges to $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$. I also have assumed that $a, b, c, d \in [0,1)$ which can be easely deduced from the relation.

When $a=0$ is quite easy to prove the statement. In my solution, I found a number $n$ for which $\{nd\}+\{nc\}>1$ which is impossible because $\{nb\}<1$. Anyways, my proof is pretty long  so I am not going to write it, but there are also proofs for this on this forum. I will attach the link here:

[How prove this $\{a\}\cdot\{b\}\cdot\{c\}=0$ if $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089274/how-prove-this-a-cdot-b-cdot-c-0-if-lfloor-na-rfloor-lfloor-nb-rf)

I do not think this is going to help in the main proof because when $a$ is not $0$, this idea of construction is not really useful because I have 2 fractional parts in  both of right and left hand.

*Note: $\{x\}$ means fractional part of $x$.*
My question is different from that with 3 fractional parts, which is easier. That question is a particular case of mine when one of the 4 numbers $a, b, c, d$ is 0. The general case is more complicated, so my question is not a DUBLICATE. If it so, then show me how, instead of closing my question. Prove me I'm wrong and show me how that old question will solve the general case, my question.

Comment: Does {x} mean the fractional part of $x$? You should make that explicit in your question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought that everybody knows what that means and is not necesary, but you are right, I should have been more explicit.